# VLOOKUP in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Lets say I have 3 columns

```
A       B       C
1      8        0
2      9        0.3
3      15       0.1
4      16       0.01
5      17       0.02
6      18       0.05
```

I need to find values in column c which are greater than 0.1 and less than -0.1. This I can do using the conditional format tab. Once these values are found I need to find the corresponding values in column A and then using those values I need to find the values in column B in which the difference between values in column A and column B is less than 8. For example, lets us take 0.3 in column C, the corresponding value in column A is 2. Looking at all values in column B I see 8-2<8, so I need to print in column D. I also need to print 9-2 since this is less than 8. However I should not print 15-3 since this value is greater than 8. I know I need to use VLOOKUP but I am lost on how to proceed . Could some please help me out?

```
A       B       C        D
1      8        0
2      9        0.3      6,7
3      15       0.1
4      16       0.01
5      17       0.02
6      18       0.05
```

Output sample for the second row with 6,7. The way to get 6,7 is as follows. Since in column C 0.3> 0.1 where 0.1 is defined by us(conditional format) , we take all values from column B. Each value in column B is subtracted from column A(we take the absolute value after the subtraction) . For example for 0.3 , the corresponding value in column A is 2. We subtract this from each and every value in column B. 2-8,2-9,2-15,2-16,2-17,2-18 and so on. From these values we choose only those values less than 8(defined by us again). So the only 2 values are 6,7 since the absolute value of everything else is greater than 8. We print this value in column D.

Comment: Your question is not clear. `Looking at all values in column B I see 8-2<8` - I don't see that. `so I need to print in column D.` - print what? Please edit your question. The data sample shows the "before". Add a data sample that shows the desired result and explain the logic in some more detail.

Comment: "However I should not print 15-3 since this value is greater than 8" - I assume you mean because it's not greater than 0.1? Otherwise, wouldn't it apply because 8-3 and 9-3 are both less than 8?

Answer (score 0):

It's a confusingly written question, but I think I understand what you're asking for. Put this into cell D1 and fill down:

```
=IF(AND(OR(C1>0.1,C1<-0.1),LEN(IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"0,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"1,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+2,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"2,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+3,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"3,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+4,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"4,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+5,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"5,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+6,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"6,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+7,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"7,",""))>1),LEFT(IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"0,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"1,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+2,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"2,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+3,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"3,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+4,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"4,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+5,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"5,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+6,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"6,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+7,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"7,",""),LEN(IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"0,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"1,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+2,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"2,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+3,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"3,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+4,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"4,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+5,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"5,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+6,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"6,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+7,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"7,",""))-1),"")
```

It's a long formula, but it's actually the same core formula written three times (once to determine length of string, once to return it and once more to remove the trailing ",").

I've assumed values will be positive and you meant >0.1 rather >=0.1 (you were inconsistent on the latter point per my comment on your question).

You can change the range to include more rows or the entire column if you wish.

A shorter version that will leave you with a "," at the end of your final value is this (just for your ease of understanding on how it works):

```
=IF(OR(C1>0.1,C1<-0.1),IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"0,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+1,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"1,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+2,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"2,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+3,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"3,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+4,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"4,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+5,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"5,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+6,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"6,","")&IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1+7,$B$1:$B$6,0))),"7,",""),"")
```